# handleResult called multiple times on executeAsync?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, firefox-addon, storage

Following the [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage) doc on MDC I've written something to read some history and show it in a textbox:

```
var dbConnection = database.getDBConnection();

var getHistoryStatement = dbConnection.createStatement("SELECT destinationUrl FROM uploadHistory ORDER BY id DESC");

getHistoryStatement.executeAsync({
    handleResult: function(aResultSet){
        var newHistoryString = "";
        for (var row = aResultSet.getNextRow(); row; row = aResultSet.getNextRow()) {
            newHistoryString += row.getResultByName("destinationUrl") + "\n";
        }

        document.getElementById("historyText").value = newHistoryString;
    },

    handleError: function(aError){
    },

    handleCompletion: function(aReason){
    }
});
```

However this is failing because handleResult is getting called twice on different threads: one with the first 3 results and one with the rest of the results. I can't find anything in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozIStorageStatement) about this behavior and google turns up nothing. Anyone know of this behavior or how to get handleResult to be called only once with all the results?

This is running on Firefox 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you mean to say  it was getting called on different threads; the callback is always invoked on the thread that `executeAsync` was called on.  `handleResult` can be called more than once, and [that behavior is documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozIStorageStatementCallback#handleResult%28%29) (although you may not have looked at that page).

Comment: Oh thanks, I did miss that page. I guess it may not have been on another thread, but I had some alert() statements in there and I had two showing up at a time, which made me think the two callbacks were happening at once. Also Chromebug failed to hit a breakpoint on the first callback, oddly.

Comment: When the alert dialog is showing, the event loop spins, which means your handleResult can be reentered (this is why nested even loops are generally considered to be bad).